# Bash create a path with variables divided by _ and check if exist

Tags: bash

In Bash, I am trying to create a path with two variables within:

```
/path/to/my/file/${variable1_-}${variable2}/Still/some/path
```

My variable2 is always set, but the variable1 might be empty and in that case I don't want to print the "_"

I have tried the line above, but doesn't seem to be correct.
Can someone help in getting the right path printed?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: The `_` is part of the variable. It won't be printed alone in any case.

Comment: You are right, so the variable doesn't get any print because variable1_ does not exist

Comment: how can I make it that only if exist $variable1 then also the _ in between is printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a simple typo (the underscore should be after the separator, not part of the variable name) and you want to include the underscore if `variable1` is set, not it it's unset (so plus instead of minus in the parameter expansion; and add a colon to also cover the set but empty case). Presumably you also want to include the actual value of `variable1` when it's set.

```
/path/to/my/file/${variable1}${variable1:+_}${variable2}/Still/some/path
```

or equivalently, nested

```
/path/to/my/file/${variable1:+${variable1}_}${variable2}/Still/some/path
```

where the braces before the underscore are necessary to separate the variable name from the literal text.

Comment: Hi..I see. Anyway the line is not correctly working. ${variable1+${variable1}_}${variable2} is printing _value2 when first variable is empty. For that you need the : before ${variable1:+${variable1}_}${variable2} That will fix your answer. Nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash
${parameter:+word}

## set also variable1

```
variable1=VAR1
variable2=VAR2
variable3=${variable1:+_}
echo /path/to/my/file/${variable1}${variable3}${variable2}/Still/some/path
```

## set only variable2

```
variable1=
variable2=VAR2
variable3=${variable1:+_}
echo /path/to/my/file/${variable1}${variable3}${variable2}/Still/some/path
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few more lines of code this could work:

```
run () {
    prefix="" # empty
    if [ -n "$variable1" ]; then
        prefix="${variable1}_"
    fi
    echo "/path/to/my/file/${prefix}${variable2}/Still/some/path"
}

# set only variable2
variable2=var2
run
# set also variable1
variable1=var1
run
```

output:

```
/path/to/my/file/var2/Still/some/path
/path/to/my/file/var1_var2/Still/some/path
```

**description:**

`-n` tests if the string is not empty, in that case I fill `prefix` with `variable1` and the underscore